# How to convert dataframe containing date into list of list with correct date format and save in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

How to write dates of dataframe in a file.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

writeFile = open("dates.csv","w+")
writer = csv.writer(writeFile)

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = '01-09-2019', end = '30-09-2019'))
Convert2List = dates.values.tolist()
for row in Convert2List:
    writer.writerow(row)

writeFile.close()
```

My actual values are:

- 1.54699E+18
- 1.54708E+18
- 1.54716E+18
- 1.54725E+18
- 1.54734E+18

And the expected values should be:

1. 01-09-2019
2. 02-09-2019
3. 03-09-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a pandas dataframe you can just use the method `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` and set the parameters ([link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a write to file function build-in. Try:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = '01-09-2019', end = '30-09-2019'))

#print (dates)             # check here if the dates is written correctly.

dates.to_csv('dates.csv')  # writes the dataframe directly to a file.
```

The date.csv file gives me:

```
,0
0,2019-01-09
1,2019-01-10
2,2019-01-11
3,2019-01-12

...snippet...

262,2019-09-28
263,2019-09-29
264,2019-09-30
```

Changing date order to get date range September for default settings:

`dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = '2019-09-01', end = '2019-09-30'))`

Gives:

> 0_29 entries for 30 days of September.

Furthermore, changing the date order for custom settings:

`dates[0] = pd.to_datetime(dates[0]).apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))`

Gives you:

1. 01-09-2019
2. 02-09-2019
3. 03-09-2019
4. ...etc.